# Entity framework connection string enable to connect to DB server

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework

I'm using the entity framework in a winforms application.

When i set **scsb.DataSource ="localhost"** every thing works fine but when i try to connect to onother DB server i got an exception:

> "**The underlying provider failed on Open**."

```
public DistributionSSEntities1 Connection()
{
    var scsb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    scsb.DataSource = "192.168.1.100";
    scsb.InitialCatalog = "DistributionSS";
    scsb.IntegratedSecurity = true;
    //------------------------
    EntityConnectionStringBuilder builder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder.Metadata ="res://*/Model.Model.csdl|res://*/Model.Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.Model.msl";
    builder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
    builder.ProviderConnectionString = scsb.ConnectionString;
    DistributionSSEntities1 db = new DistributionSSEntities1(builder.ToString());
    return db;
}
```

Comment: Check this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/091b1eac-4ed6-43b8-b184-a713d1f2b9eb)

Comment: Do that server works? try to access it first using your vs studio. check also your web config connection string.

Comment: are you sure you have windows authentication account for the server you are trying to access

Comment: The _"The underlying provider failed on Open"_ exception has an InnerException which tells you exactly what is wrong. Either TCP/IP access is not enabled, the server is not running or not accessible (firewall?), or the user you try to access the database with is not authorized to do so.

Comment: @CodeCaster: if the sql server rejected the connection/login attempt you're almost certainly NOT going to get valid info from an inner exception - see my edit on why.

Comment: @QuintonBernhardt thanks, but that's not true. You _will_ get a useful exception, it'll say "Logon failed for user X", just not the reason the logon failed (account expired, incorrect password, and so on). You'll also receive a useful error in case of connectivity errors. Contrary to your answer, step 1 always is to check the exception and its inner one. Especially when dealing with connectivity errors, as those hardly ever end up in the server' logs.

Comment: @CodeCaster i guess it's a matter of opinion.  I don't see a message of "Logon failed for user X" being at all usefull if there are bunch of underlying reasons why you would get the same message.  It means that you have to check all those reasons which btw could be as simple as TCP/IP not allowed.  The quickest and most accurate way to determine the cause of a sql server rejected connection is to go to the logs; IMO.

Comment: @QuintonBernhardt While I agree that server logs can aid in analyzing specific issues, in general the exception does tell enough. If you see an error that user X cannot access a certain database, and you know you have never granted that user access, you know what to do and don't need the server logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public DistributionSSEntities Connection()
    {
        string ConString = "SERVER=192.168.1.100;DATABASE=DistributionSS;UID=sa;PASSWORD=125;";
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder SCB= new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConString);
        //------------------------
        EntityConnectionStringBuilder builder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.Metadata = "res://*/Model.Model.csdl|res://*/Model.Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.Model.msl";
        builder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
        builder.ProviderConnectionString = SCB.ConnectionString;
        DistributionSSEntities db = new DistributionSSEntities(builder.ToString());
        return db;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Has the remote Sql been setup to allow remote connections? Has the remote Sql been allowed access through the windows firewall... there's so many reasons why it wouldn't connect.

You're using Integrated Security - which may work great for a local Sql; but the network user that your WinForm app is running under must have the correct rights to access the remote box.

I'd suggest to start eliminating possibilities do the following:

1. Check the Sql logs on the target server.  That always has the exact reason why an attemp failed - not the watered down version you get through the exception. (eg. C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log)
2. Connect to it using a sql username password - not integrated security to make sure it's not that
3. Firewall

**EDIT**

It's important to remember that the error messages return to the client regarding login attempt failures are purposefully obscure or without information - to limit an attacker gaining enough information to improve the attack (see [the technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366351%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for proof).  So checking the Sql Server logs is a necessity - if your login/connection attempt actually made it to the server.

**From Article:**

> To increase security, the error message that is returned to the client
>   deliberately hides the nature of the authentication error. However, in
>   the SQL Server error log, a corresponding error contains an error
>   state that maps to an authentication failure condition. Compare the
>   error state to the following list to determine the reason for the
>   login failure.